# Поиск одинаковых элементов в двух массивах

Tags: php

Есть два массива `$first = ['one','two','three'];$second= ['five','four','three'];` 
Вопрос, как сделать проверку на одинаковые элементы, что-то типа

```
if(in_array($first,$second)){
echo 'yes'}
else {echo 'no'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пересечение массивов: array_intersect

```
$intersection = array_intersect(['one', 'two', 'three'], ['five', 'four', 'three']);
// ['three']
```

После этого остается воспользоваться вышеупомянутым in_array для поиска элементов в пересечении:

```
if (in_array('three', $intersection)) ...
```